# save draggableview weight

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

I have a question related to draggableview (DV) integrated in Drupal 9. How can I save DV weight field value in other content type field called "field_priority" ?

I found this info but it's using form submit event to get the field value. not clear about how I can integrate this code into my custom module. [save weight field value](https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/post-installation/2020-11-09/draggable-views-custom-field-to-save-weight-index)

DV custom view

[image]

Content Types custom field

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: hi, finally I solved the issue. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I did to solve the requirement. Installed a module called [Sortableview](https://www.drupal.org/project/sortableviews) This one is similar to Draggableview module except it can save the position value ( After drag and drop the question ) into custom content type field.

Here are the steps:

- composer installed the Sortableview module
- create a new integer field called field_priority (content type)
- added that field as a sorting criteria to the custom Drupal view
- added **Sortableviews: Drag and drop** handler as a field to the custom view
- change the format to the Sortable table
- finally added the **Save Sortableviews changes** handler to the footer of the custom view